# model doesn't move like it have weight apply

Tags: rigging

this model when in pose mode it just move entry model. like it doesn't get effect of weight system.
*I already auto-weight it*
[image]

Comment: What did you move?

Comment: I just select some 3 4 part of rig and move it all. what I want is how to move it like riged model that not stretch the model. 

Comment: Well some bones are only meant to be rotated, if you move or scale them, your model gets stretched.